# How to test the convergence for $\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{ln\left(n\right)}}\right)^{n+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to test the convergence for

$$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln\left(n\right)}}\right)^{n+1}$$

Can I use the comparison test for this one?
For example:

$n≥\ln(n)$

$\sqrt{n}\ge \sqrt{\ln\left(n\right)}$

$-\sqrt{n}\le -\ln\left(n\right)$

$\frac{1}{-\sqrt{n}}\ge \frac{1}{-\sqrt{\ln\left(n\right)}}$

and then I use the the p series for p = 1 and say that this diverges? or can I only use this inequality for convergent?

Thanks :)

Comment: Ratio test could do the trick. Hint: prove that $\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln\left(n+1\right)}}\right)^{n+2}}{\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln\left(n\right)}}\right)^{n+1}}<1$.

Comment: I suspect that Vivid's answer is the intent of the problem composer.  The only analysis required is that : [1] as $n \to \infty,~\ln(n) \to \infty~~$ and therefore, so does $~\sqrt{\ln(n)}.~~$ [2] $1 < n < m \implies \ln(n) < \ln(m) \implies \sqrt{\ln(n)} < \sqrt{\ln(m)}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** After rewriting it as
$$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\:\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln\left(n\right)}}\right)^{n+1} = \sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\: (-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln\left(n\right)}}\right)^{n+1} = \sum_{n=3}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} a_n$$
notice that it is an [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) and luckily $a_n\to0$ decreasing monotonically as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! The easiest method comparing to everyone elses!

Answer (score 3):

For large enough $n$, $|\frac{-1}{\sqrt(ln(n))}| \leq \frac{1}{2}$. So as $n$ increases its absolutely bounded by a geometric series. So by comparison of series ur series converges absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vivid did, consider
$$a_n=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log\left(n\right)}}\right)^{n+1}\implies \log(a_n)=-\frac 12(n+1) \log (\log (n))$$
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=\frac{1}{2} (n+1) \log (\log (n))-\frac{1}{2} (n+2) \log (\log (n+1))$$ Using Taylor series
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=-\frac{1}{2} \log (\log (n))-\frac{1}{2 \log (n)}+\cdots$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1} }{a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2 \log (n)}}}{\sqrt{\log (n)}}\quad \to ~~0$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln \left(n+1\right)}}\right)^{n+2}}{\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln \left(n\right)}}\right)^{n+1}}\right)
&=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(-\ln ^{\frac{1+n}{2}}\left(n\right)\cdot \ln ^{-1-\frac{n}{2}}\left(1+n\right)\right)\\
&=-\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\ln ^{\frac{1+n}{2}}\left(n\right)\cdot \ln ^{-1-\frac{n}{2}}\left(1+n\right)\right)\\
&=-\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{\ln ^{n+1}\left(n\right)\cdot \ln ^{-n-2}\left(1+n\right)}\right)\\
&=-\sqrt{\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\ln ^{n+1}\left(n\right)\cdot \ln ^{-n-2}\left(1+n\right)\right)}\\
&=-\sqrt{\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\exp \left(\ln ^2\left(n\right)\left(n+1\right)+\ln ^2\left(n+1\right)\left(-n-2\right)\right)\right)}\\
&=-\sqrt{\exp{\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\ln ^2\left(n\right)\left(n+1\right)+\ln ^2\left(n+1\right)\left(-n-2\right)\right)}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\ln ^2\left(n\right)\left(n+1\right)+\ln ^2\left(n+1\right)\left(-n-2\right)\right)$ is $-\infty$, the limit of the whole expression is $0$. Hence, convergent by ratio test.